# OAuth.io connection failed

Tags: javascript, html, oauth

I'm new to web programming and I try to use oauth.io in my web-app. I finished configurations to facebook and Google due to the instruction.  Everything works fine when i tested the configuration from their site. However when i tried to implemented to my webapp, OAuth won't connect to the provider.

I loaded the oauth.js in html, created a button in html and use `onclick="pop"` to invoke the function in javascript. And within the `pop()` function in javascript I've added:

```
OAuth.initialize('the-public-key-in-my-acc");
OAuth.popup('facebook', function(err, res) { if (err) { alert(something)});
```

Then I click the button. a popup window just flashed up and closed immediately. I've also tried to use OAuth.redirect and redirect it to http://oauth-io.github.io/oauth-js or my localhost, but then it says connection failed.

Is there something missing/wrong in the implementation?

Thanks a lot for the help.

PS: I'm working on localhost and i've tried to set redirect-url to localhost:portnr. but still failed. :(

Here is the sample code i've written:

Html:

```
<div><button onclick="oauthPop()">Try OAuth-io</button></div>
```

JS:

```
var oauthPop = function() {
OAuth.initialize('my-pub-key-on-authio');
OAuth.popup('facebook', function(err, res) { // or OAuth.callback
    // handle error with err
    if (err) {
        alert ("error")
    } else {
        // get my name from fb
        res.get('/me').done(function(data) {
            alert(data.name)
        })
    }});
}
```

Comment: Do you have jQuery correctly loaded?

Comment: hum, I wasn't using jQuery, I'm using javascript. Is jQuery is a must for oauth.io? I thought it shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: `OAuth.popup()` doesn't need jQuery to work but `res.get('/me')` use [jQuery.ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) behind the scene.

Answer (score 2):

OAuth.io needs to have jQuery loaded to make HTTP requests using the result of `OAuth.popup()`. It use [jQuery.ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) behind the scene to let you a well-known function with all the option you might need.

Comment: I am also facing this issue but not get any solution till that "res" is undefined in OAuth.popup('facebook', function(err, res) {}) this is only happen in live server not on local please help

Comment: @RaviPatidar if `res` is empty, you should have something in `err` that describe why there is an error (console.log(err)). Have you add your live server to the whitelisted domain in OAuth.io?

Comment: yes I have added console.log(err) there is an error msg so that I used another way to get followers list using php Thanks for reply @Thibaud arnault