# OAuth.io popup window closing immediately

Tags: javascript, twitter, oauth, oauth.io

I'm using oauth.io to handle authorization of users' Twitter accounts to pull data from the Twitter API. I use the code exactly as in the demo, inserting my public key and using 'twitter' as the provider:

```
OAuth.initialize('key'); //OAuth.io public key
    OAuth.popup('twitter')
    .done(function (result) {
        // Perform API calls
        console.log(result);
    })
    .fail(function (error) {
        // Handle errors
    });
```

When I open the page, a popup window opens, but then closes immediately before I can see anything or diagnose what's going wrong.

I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23083817/oauth-io-connection-failed) but it didn't seem to address the issue of the popup closing, just that the author needed to include jQuery, which I've already done.

Questions:

1. Is there anything I might have done wrong in configuring or setting up my apps, either on oauth.io or Twitter?
2. Is there a way to diagnose what's happening in the popup between when it opens and closes?

Comment: Do you have all the relevant domain(s) (including local testing domains) in the white list for your app? I got tripped up on this whilst testing on multiple devices. [screenshot](http://puu.sh/dqjl9/8b3c0d0892.png)

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I have the exact same problem at the moment. I'm running this all on localhost.

Comment: @London804, turned out to be a typo in my domain whitelist, as suggested in the comment above. Doubt that helps you on localhost, but if you have any other info, post it and I'll see if I can help!

Answer (score 2):

You'll see this exact behavior if you've already granted access to the Facebook app. To remove access for the app and test again, follow these steps:

- When logged in to your FB account, go to https://www.facebook.com/bookmarks/apps.
- Click the gear icon next to the app in question.
- Click "Remove App", then confirm by clicking "Remove" on the resulting confirmation dialog.

Test the oauth.io integration again, and you should see the expected login and/or authorization popup dialogs.

Comment: It appears that the URL may have changed. I was able to click "remove app" by clicking on the "Settings" button towards the top-right of the Apps table.

Comment: @jdiver I am also using this as a login mechanism, but it does not work. How would that be fixed?